# javascript match get all class names with numbers in them

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the classes of the body tag that have numbers in them, but got stuck with the regex

```
<body class='UjQWin PEfnhb s21aSi'>

var matches = document.body.className.match(/[0-9]+/);
if (matches) {
    id = matches;
    //document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = id;
  console.log(id) //expected output s21aSi 
}
```

Is it possible to get the output as s21aSi in this case?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an array from the `.classList` property and filter that array, here is an example:

```js
const result = [...document.body.classList].filter(cl => /\d/.test(cl));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<body class='UjQWin PEfnhb s21aSi'>
```

Comment: Hi Titus, I am suggesting basically the same, right? Or is there any serious flaw in my solution? Why is it downvoted?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, they have the same effect, I cannot see any flaws, splitting on space is safe since space is not a valid class name character. Is frustrating when people downvote and they don't leave a comment with an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You may split with whitespace (`.split(/\s+/)`) and filter using `/\d/` (digit matching) pattern:

```js
var matches = document.body.className.split(/\s+/).filter(m => /\d/.test(m));
console.log(matches)
```

```html
<body class='UjQWin PEfnhb s21aSi'>
```